# mailto not working with phonegap

Tags: cordova, mailto, phonegap-build

So my latest phone gap  project works fine in the browser,

I have an email icon with a simple mailto href link, but when i run my xcode project its not bringing up the email in the simulator?

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Nat

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the phonegap plugin EmailComposer .

Mailto command won't work on all platforms. That's the reason why this plugin is mostly used.

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer

All the guidelines to use it can be found at it's readme.txt

i used this plugin its work perfectly in my apps